# curl: (7) error when i try installing Homebrew on iMac

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

Setup iMac OSX 10.7.4,

Hi there,

I am trying to install Homebrew on my iMac but I keep getting an error. I am following the instructions on https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation

I have Xcode installed and the Java Developer update which it specifies on the website.

I open Terminal and paste

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
```

But I keep getting the error

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Has anyone any suggestions?

EDIT:

Just to add I am on a college network incase its relevant

EDIT: I have also reinstalled Curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was Curl not being configured to bypass my proxy.

One of they guys here in the office sorted it out for me. From what I understand the settings on curl had to be changed and not the proxy.

Hopefully this will help others in future.

Comment: What are the curl settings that need to be changed?

Answer (score 2):

For my specific case, I use SOCKS proxy for all traffic. So my installation command is:

```
 ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL --socks5 127.0.0.1:30000 https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

where `127.0.0.1:30000` is the SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Something is blocking your connection to github.  Try accessing the url https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb in your browser.

Comment: Hi James

When i visit that link in my browser i get 

`#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby`
`# This script installs to /usr/local only. To install elsewhere you can just`
`# untar https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tarball/master anywhere you like.`


more code here


`ohai "Installation successful!"`
`puts "You should run `brew doctor' *before* you install anything."`
`puts "Now type: brew help"`

So im guessing thats the right page

Comment: @Deepend Try running `/usr/bin/curl https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb` and check for the same output.

Answer (score 0):

I too had same problem.
The recipe for proxies should add `--noproxy` after `curl` statement

```
ruby -e "$(curl --noproxy -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this error and in my instance it was because my firewall was blocking or preventing outbound connections to Japan where it was trying to pull down the ruby version.  Once the firewall rule was adjusted to allow the connections to that country everything worked fine.